# Pandas breaking rows and preventing Google Data Studio to read file correctly

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, looker-studio

I have a large dataframe that I'm sending to csv using `pandas.to_csv()`
When I look at in using print it seems alright:

```
print(df.name[160])
--> ALEXANDRE SILVA FARINAZZO

print(df.name[161])
--> ARCHANGELA GABRIELA PRATI FAVARO
```

When I send it to csv and open in Excel I notice that Pandas, when using to_csv, breaks some lines:

[image]

I thought it could be something with Excel, but when I import it to Google Data Studio (without saving it or anything) those are exactly the problematic lines I get:

[image]

The other problematic rows follow the same problem pattern.
Is there a way to avoid it? Why is that happening?

**EDIT**

Following @Quang Hoang's suggestion I included a sep='\t' in the to_csv sentence. The problem shifted. Apparently Google Data Studio doesn't recognize '\t' as separator.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Tried to take out all of the commas in the file using `df['column'].str.replace(",","")` and apparently commas are not the problem. I'm getting the very first problem again:

[image]

Comment: Your cells might contain `,`. you could try `sep='\t'` so you have a tsv file.

Comment: Changed to another problem now, I will post an edit

Comment: Apparently Google Data Studio doesn't recognize '\t' as separator

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it.
Actually there was two problems:

**Problem a)** In some columns there were some hidden `"\n"`. Had to make a `print(repr(string))` to find it out and then `str.replace('\n',"")`

**Problem b)** I noticed there was a prob in some rows that had cells with very long strings when uploading to Google Data Studio. Not sure what caused it but I tried shortening some character-dense columns with `df['column'].loc[df['column'].str.len() > 1000] = df['column'].str[:1000]` and it solved the prob. Not ideal because I missed some data, but worked.